# Вставить в пустые ячейки столбца значения предыдущего

Tags: sql, sql-server

Как с помощью оператора UPDATE заполнить пустые ячейки значением предыдущей в столбце?
Например, чтобы таблица

```
id      date
1       11.11.2019
2       11.11.2019
3       12.11.2019
4       (пусто)
5       13.11.2019
6       (пусто)    
7       (пусто)
8       14.11.2019
```

стала такой:

```
id      date
1       11.11.2019
2       11.11.2019
3       12.11.2019
4       12.11.2019
5       13.11.2019
6       13.11.2019    
7       13.11.2019
8       14.11.2019
```

Comment: Дата, при увеличении id, не убывает?

Comment: @AntonShchyrov , нет

Answer (score 1):

```
Update
  `dates` as d
SET
  date = (
    SELECT
      date
    FROM
      `dates`
    WHERE
      id = (d.id -1)
  )
WHERE
  date is NULL
```

Comment: Ну и кто сказал, что пропущенных id нет?

Comment: @Qwertiy а кто сказал, что есть?

Comment: @Qwertiy я увидел пример, написал для него ответ. Если есть пропущенные id, то проще уже полную выгрузку сделать и пройтись по записям.

Comment: @Shiki спасибо, такой запрос сработал, только ругалось на алиас, поэтому убрал его из запроса

Answer (score 1):

Из условия

> Дата, при увеличении id, не убывает

```
UPDATE
  `dates` as d
SET
  date = (
    SELECT
      MAX(date)
    FROM
      `dates`
    WHERE
      id < d.id AND
      date is NOT NULL
  )
WHERE
  date is NULL
```

или

```
UPDATE
  `dates` as d
SET
  date = (
    SELECT TOP 1
      date
    FROM
      `dates`
    WHERE
      id < d.id AND
      date is NOT NULL
    ORDER BY
      id DESC
  )
WHERE
  date is NULL
```

Comment: Зачем max, просто TOP (1) ... ORDER BY id DESC

Comment: @DenisRubashkin можно и так

Comment: Серверу ведь неизвестна информация о неубывающей дате - он будет честно искать максимальную дату для диапазона. Это будет наверняка дольше и тяжелее, чем найти первую попавшуюся.